Printing out the number one by one

Read in a positive integer.  Print the integer in decimal, one digit at a time.  Do this using a function that prints an integer, one digit per line.
Example: 13456
1
3
4
5
6


I've tried to do this with a for loop, but I don't know how to stop it with the i value always changing.
I tried to %10 and /10 the whole thing, but I don't know how to implement it.
This is what I wrote so far:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int oneatatime(int number){

    //vector<int> contents; //for how much the contents of the for loop has to go through
    vector<int> forremainder; 
    vector<int> fordivide;

    int divide = number / 10; //the divided number using / operation
    int remainder = number % 10; //the remainder using % operation
    int newdigit = 0;
    int digitsum = 0;
    int newnum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){ //how would i replace the old one with the new one? // contents.size() == 1 how do we make it the same as how many numbers in the number

        fordivide[i] = divide;
        int n = fordivide[i] = divide;
        //remainder = number % 10;
        //fordivide.push_back(divide);
        //n.push_back(remainder); // will put it in the array of 

        //fordivide.push_back(divide);

        //forremainder.push_back(remainder);
        fordivide.push_back(n);

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << fordivide[i] << endl;
        //cout << forremainder[i] << endl;
    }

    /*do{
        divide
    }while(newnum == 1)*/
}

int main(){
    int number = 12346;

    oneatatime(number);
}

I don't know what to do, please help.

Tactical note: If you are reading in a number and you're not going to use it as a number, like do math on it, you're probably better off reading in a string. With a string, all of the digits are already separated and you just need a loop to iterate and print all of the characters in it.

@user4581301 I think the whole point of this exercise is to figure out how to do it numerically.

You stop when the value becomes 0 after you divide by 10.

Important note: dividing the number once doesn't do you any good. Inside the loop you need to use the modulo operator, % to isolate one digit. int digit = number % 10;. Once you have that digit you divide the number to remove the digit. number = number / 10; Repeat until you are out of digits. This will give you the number backwards so you'll have to figure out how to reverse it. Recursion works really well.

The access to the empty std::vector seems like a good place to start debugging.

rough algorithm for recursion: Rather than using a loop, you write a function that takes a number If that number is zero, you're done. Return. Otherwise isolates digit with %.  then the function calls itself with 1/10th of the number and prints out the print out the isolated digit. Work through this on paper and you should be able to see how it prints the digits in the right order.

Demo with std::to_string or recursion.

@Barmar or it's to realise that finding an appropriate representation makes things easy

Recursion: (1) If more than 1 digit, print all previous digits; (2) print last digit. For all previous digits: num / 10. For last digit: num % 10. Some of the answers to this thread look really scary (to me!)

void printDigits(unsigned int num) {
  long reversedNum = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
    reversedNum = reversedNum * 10 + num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }
  while (reversedNum > 0) {
    std::cout << reversedNum % 10 << std::endl;
    reversedNum /= 10;
  }
}

The printDigits function prints the digits of an unsigned integer num from highest to lowest order. It does this by first reversing the number into a new variable reversedNum.
The function initializes reversedNum to 0.
It then enters a loop that continues until num becomes 0. In each iteration, it extracts the last digit of num using % 10, appends it to reversedNum by multiplying reversedNum by 10 and adding the extracted digit, and removes the last digit from num by dividing it by 10.
After the loop, reversedNum contains the reversed version of num.
The function then enters another loop that prints the digits of reversedNum from right to left. In each iteration, it prints the last digit of reversedNum using % 10 and removes it by dividing reversedNum by 10.
Note: Although the function reverses the number first, it is not strictly necessary to do so to print the digits in order. The loop could simply print the digits of num directly without reversing it.

It does this by first reversing the number into a new variable reversedNum -- What happens if the reversed number cannot fit into an unsigned int?  Assume that unsigned int is 32 bits.  What happens if the original number is 1234567899? -- the reverse is 9987654321, which exceeds what a 32 bit integer can hold

Yes，When reversing an integer number and an overflow occurs, defining reversedNum as a long can avoid this phenomenon.

@IceRiver -- side note: long is required to be at least as large as int; it is not required to be larger. So using long might not evade this problem. On desktop systems it's larger, but that's not something you can absolutely rely on.

Be cautious with this. If you reverse 1000 as a number, you get 1, not 0001, and will not provide the correct output. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/MzPhTbcjo

Good code is self explaining (the comments I put in there are mostly educational, not about what the program is doing). Learn to write small functions with clear names. Like this
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // for reverse

//using namespace std; <-- don't use this

// learn to use namespaces
// and to never put code of your own in the global namespace
namespace number_output
{
    // helper and details stuff
    namespace details
    {

        // don't be afraid to make small functions
        // usually if you feel you have to write
        // comments for a few lines of code
        // you know you have to make a function
        char last_digit_of_value_as_char(unsigned int value)
        {
            char last_digit = (value % 10); 
            return (last_digit + '0');
        }

        std::string make_backward_string(unsigned int value)
        {
            std::string output;

            do
            {
                char c = last_digit_of_value_as_char(value);
                output.push_back(c);
                value /= 10;
            } while (value > 0);

            return output;
        }

    }

    std::string make_string(unsigned int value)
    {
        std::string backward_output = details::make_backward_string(value);

        // using std::reverse makes your code more readable
        // it shows what you want to do (not how it is done)
        // this is abstraction at work :)
        std::reverse(backward_output.begin(), backward_output.end());
        return backward_output;
    }

} // namespace number_output

int main()
{
    std::cout << number_output::make_string(0) << "\n"; // test a corner case
    std::cout << number_output::make_string(12345) << "\n";
}


std::to_string ;-)

@Jarod For production code, but ofcourse :)

For fun, let's solve this with some recursion. Yes, recursion is usually looked upon as "bad," but an int will never hold enough digits for this simple program to overflow the stack, and this has the benefit of being very simple to implement.
#include <iostream>

void print_digits(int num) {
    if (num == 0) return;

    print_digits(num / 10);

    std::cout << (num % 10) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    print_digits(123456);
}

Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6

This works because the recursion being before the print makes the output from the last recursive call appear first.
If you need to save the digits in a vector in the same order, the same approach can work.
void save_digits(int num, std::vector<int>& vec) {
    if (num == 0) return;

    save_digits(num / 10, vec);

    vec.push_back(num % 10);
}

As noted in comments, this will not work for passing it 0, but in any other circumstance, we wouldn't want a leading zero. One way to overcome that would be to pass a flag indicating whether or not we're in the initial call.
void save_digits(int num, std::vector<int>& vec, bool init_call=true) {
    if (num == 0 && !init_call) return;

    save_digits(num / 10, vec, false);

    vec.push_back(num % 10);
}


print_digits(0); prints nothing... (I have added a demo link in main comment with recursion.)

Addressed in an edit. Thank you.

Over complicated :-) if (num >= 10 /* or num / 10 != 0 */) {recursion(num / 10); } job(num % 10);

This answer is geared towards beginners. It avoids all but the most basic types from the Standard Library. That is why, for instance, std::vector was chosen over std::stack.
It's a long one, because it briefly discusses topics such as implicit type conversion, integer literals, psuedocode, and so on, which arise during the development of a solution, and which the OP is just beginning to learn about. It is the sort of answer I would have liked to read, back when I was a student at his level.
Unfortunately that means that advanced programmers and professionals will probably decide: TL;DR. That's okay. I get it. You can see the finished program at the end of this answer.
Eliminate warnings
When I compiled the code supplied in the original question, I got this warning:

warning C4715: 'oneatatime': not all control paths return a value

In general, you should treat warning messages as errors, and modify a program so it compiles without warnings. Here, that is easy.

Solution 1: Change the return type of function oneatatime to void. This is the solution I adopted.
Solution 2: Return an arbitrary value, such as 0.

Avoid using namespace std;
Next, I deleted the line using namespace std;. Professional programmers avoid this using directive, and so should student programmers. It is a shame that many textbooks take the lazy approach, and teach beginners to use it.
It's okay to prefix names from the Standard Library with std::. Except in a few circumstances, usually having to do with something called argument-dependent lookup, that is what professionals do.
For this program, I added std:: to each name from the Standard Library.
Avoid std::endl
This output manipulator does two things.

Write a newline character to the output stream.
Flush the output buffer associated with the stream.

For reasons of efficiency, stream I/O is usually buffered. Rather than writing characters one-at-a-time to a stream, characters are collected in a buffer. Later on, the buffer is sent to the stream as a block. Usually, this happens automatically, perhaps because a buffer is full, or perhaps because a buffer is tied to an input stream that has received a read request. Flushing a buffer is the process of writing its contents to a stream.
With std::cout, it is unnecessary (and inefficient) to force the buffer to be flushed. Therefore, you should avoid std::endl. Instead, just output the newline character directly. That's what I did in this program. All occurrences of endl have been replaced with '\n'.
std::cout << '\n';  // Avoid `std::endl` by outputting the newline character.

Use type unsigned long long
This answer assumes that the assignment requires students to peel off the digits of an integer using quotient and remainder operations. We see this in the code from the OP:
// From the OP:
int divide = number / 10;     //the divided number using / operation
int remainder = number % 10;  //the remainder using % operation

The problem spec specifies that the integers are always positive. It makes sense, therefore, to use an unsigned integer type to store them. That way, you avoid the need to check for negative numbers. Type unsigned long long was chosen, because it supports the widest range of values.
In the OP, all occurrences of type int have been changed to type unsigned long long.
Quotient and remainder
Given an integer number, you can extract the rightmost digit using the the remainder operator %.
// Extract rightmost digit.
unsigned long long number = 13456ull;
auto const rightmost_digit = number % 10ull;

After you have extracted the rightmost digit, you can remove it from the original number using integer division:
// Discard the rightmost digit of `number`.
number /= 10ull;

When only one digit remains in variable number, dividing by 10 results in the value 0. Testing for 0, therefore, is how you determine that there are no more digits to extract.
Literal suffix ull means unsigned long long
In the code above, the suffix ull denotes a literal value of type unsigned long long. Because of a complex set of rules that promote and implicitly convert the types of the operands used in initializers and expressions, it turns out that ull could have been omitted.
// The integer literal 13456 will be given type `int`. So will the literal 10.
// In the code below, both are implicitly converted to type `unsigned long long`.
unsigned long long number = 13456;
auto const rightmost_digit = number % 10;

As they are small enough to be stored in an object of type int, the integer literals 13456 and 10 (above) will be given type int. Integer literals with values too big to be stored in an int will be assigned a wider type, such as long or long long, as needed.
When 13456 (an int) is used to copy-initialize a variable of a different arithmetic type (e.g., number), it will be implicity converted to that type. Similarly, when 10 is used in a mixed-mode expression, such as number % 10, the compiler will implicitly promote and/or convert one or both of the operands to a common type appropriate for the computation.
Until you have mastered the rules governing integral promotion and implicit type conversion, my advice is to avoid mixed-mode expressions, which mix operands of different types. That is why I am using the suffix ull for literals in the OP, even though the program would work fine if ull were omitted.
Even today, I frequently avoid mixed-mode, just so I don't have to analyze the implicit type conversions I would otherwise be asking the compiler to make.
A loop to extract digits
The program in the OP uses the following for-statement to extract digits. It is incorrect, because it assumes there are 5 digits in the number being processed.
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // ...
}

The correct loop tests whether number is 0.
The problem spec guarantees that number starts out with a non-zero value, so the only way it could be 0 is if all of its digits have been extracted. We want to keep looping, therefore, so long as number != 0ull
void oneatatime(unsigned long long number)
{
    // Precondition: number > 0
    std::vector<unsigned long long> digits;
    while (number != 0ull)
    {
        // Extract rightmost digit, and save in vector `digits`.
        // Discard rightmost digit.
    }

    // ...
}

Because the problem specification promises that number is not 0, the foregoing loop "meets spec." It is easy, however, to both meet spec, and extend the solution so that it handles 0. That can be accomplished by moving the test to the bottom of the loop, i.e., by using a do-while loop.
void oneatatime(unsigned long long number)
{
    std::vector<unsigned long long> digits;
    do {
        // Extract rightmost digit, and save in vector `digits`.
        // Discard rightmost digit.
    } while (number != 0ull);

    // ...
}

You may have been taught about pseudocode. It is a topic that most textbooks overdo. They require students to write out an entire function in psuedocode, and then erase it, one line at a time, as it is translated into C++ source code.
In the real world, professionals mix pseudocode with real code, often writing pseudocode as comments. That's what I did above.
These two lines are pseudocode:
// Extract rightmost digit, and save in vector `digits`.
// Discard rightmost digit.

This has the advantage that you are not wasting time writing things that must be erased.

The comments that are "psuedocode" are often left in the finished program.
Otherwise, they can be converted to function calls.

If you know you will be calling a function, you can skip the comment step. In that case, the "pseudocode" can be written directly as a function call. For each such call, add a stub function, which will be coded later, to handle the work.
I think it is overkill for this assignment, but here is what I might have done if I were going to use functions:
void oneatatime(unsigned long long number)
{
    std::vector<unsigned long long> digits;
    do {
        // I think of these function calls as "psuedocode."
        // I also think of them as "finished code."
        extract_and_save_rightmost_digit(number, digits);
        discard_rightmost_digit(number);
    } while (number != 0ull);

    // ...
}

Once again, note that using function calls, in place of psuedocode, means that a programmer does not waste time writing things that must be erased later on. No matter whether you write your pseudocode in comments or as function calls, you are writing finished code, which often remains unaltered in the final program.
Putting it all together
We know how to extract and discard digits. We know how the loop works. It is a small step to combine them. When the following loop finishes, the digits from variable number will have been extracted, and stored in vector digits.
void oneatatime(unsigned long long number)
{
    std::vector<unsigned long long> digits;
    do {
        // Extract rightmost digit, and save in vector `digits`.
        auto const rightmost_digit = number % 10ull;
        digits.push_back(rightmost_digit);

        // Discard rightmost digit.
        number /= 10ull;
    } while (number != 0ull);

    // Output vector in reverse order.
    // ...
}

The final chore is to output the vector. The foregoing loop placed digits in the vector in reverse order. The rightmost digit of the number was stored first, at the front of the vector. The leftmost digit of the number was stored last, at the back of the vector. Thus, we must output the vector in reverse order.
There are several ways to accomplish this. One simple approach is to treat the vector as a LIFO stack, and pop elements off the back of the vector. (LIFO means last-in, first-out.)
// Output vector in reverse order.
while (!digits.empty()) {
    std::cout << digits.back() << '\n';
    digits.pop_back();
}

Alternatively, you could use subscripting. In general, subscripts use type std::size_t, which you get by including the header <cstddef>.
(There is also a type defined within std::vector for subscripts, but we will ignore it for this beginner-level answer. Besides, in every implementation I have seen, it is a type alias for std::size_t.)
// Output vector in reverse order.
for (std::size_t i = digits.size(); i > 0u; --i)
    std::cout << digits[i - 1u] << '\n';

The subscripting loop can be written more consisely using a common C++ idiom for loops that count down.
The following loop relies on the fact that using an integer expression, in a place where the compiler is expecting a Boolean value, causes the integer to be implicitly converted to a bool. In such cases, 0 means false, and any non-zero value means true.
The loop also relies on postfix decrement. Before the final iteration, when i equals 1, the expression i-- also has the value 1. Thus, the loop body is executed. Before entering the loop, however, the postfix decrement occurs, thus making i equal to 0 inside the loop. The next time i-- is tested, it will have the value 0, and the loop will end.
If, for some reason, the size of the vector is 0 (which cannot happen here), then i will be initialized to 0. The expression i-- will also have the value 0, and body of the loop will not be executed.
// Output vector in reverse order.
for (auto i = digits.size(); i--;)  // must use postfix decrement!
    std::cout << digits[i] << '\n';

Finally, you could use a reverse iterator.
// Output vector in reverse order.
for (auto it{ digits.crbegin() }; it != digits.crend(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << '\n';

A complete program
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void oneatatime(unsigned long long number)
{
    std::vector<unsigned long long> digits;
    do {
        // Extract rightmost digit, and save in vector `digits`.
        auto const rightmost_digit = number % 10ull;
        digits.push_back(rightmost_digit);

        // Discard rightmost digit.
        number /= 10ull;
    } while (number != 0ull);

    // Output vector in reverse order.
    while (!digits.empty()) {
        std::cout << digits.back() << '\n';
        digits.pop_back();
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long number = 13456ull;
    oneatatime(number);
}
// end file: main.cpp

Output
As desired, the digits have been output one at a time:
1
3
4
5
6

Just for fun
Here is a four-line version of function oneatatime. It uses std::to_string from header <string>. This is what might be used in production code.
void oneatatime(unsigned long long const number) {
    auto const s{ std::to_string(number) };
    for (auto const& c : s)
        std::cout << c << '\n';
}


Yeah, I thought about that. I could handle 0, by using a do-while loop. Note, however, that the very first sentence of the OP says, "Read in a positive integer." Thus, I treated it as a precondition of the function, required to be enforced by the caller (if at all), that the argument be positive. In addition, my answer states, in two places, that the argument is guaranteed to be positive. I probably should have used do-while, anyway. Hopefully, there is still a lot for a beginner to like.

@Jarod42 Check out the updated answer. I edited it, to include do-while.
